# Writing multiple CSV files programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csv

I am writing an application that will write database tables into CSV Files.  Since many tables are over a million records, I am giving the user an option of writing large tables into files of 25,000 lines each.  I want the user to specify the initial file name in a SaveFileDialog and then append "-part1", "-part2", etc. for each new file written.  How can one programmatically write multiple files until all the data is written?  The current code I have to write the 25,000 line file is listed below.

```
    public void ExportPartition(SaveFileDialog saveFile, DataTable table)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, 1048576);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 25000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write(table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + ",");
            }
            writer.Write("\r\n");
        }
        writer.Flush();
        DisposeObjects(saveFile, writer);
    }
```

Comment: You might also want to consider handling fields that have commas in them already so the import operation does not fail.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma at the end of every line?

Comment: I just wrote this quickly, I didn't notice the comma at the end of the line.  Thanks for that.  There is not any data that contains commas in the fields, but for the sake of re-usability I should probably address this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    bool ExportPartition(string fileName, DataTable table, int batchSize, int batchNum)
    {
        string fn = string.Format("{0}-{1}{2}",                                     
                                  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                                  batchNum,
                                  Path.GetExtension(fileName));

        fn = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), fn);

        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fn))
        {
            int start = batchNum * batchSize;
            int end = start + batchSize;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                if (i >= table.Rows.Count)
                    break;

                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write(table.Rows[i][j] + ",");
                }
                writer.Write("\r\n");
            }

            return table.Rows.Count <= end;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    void WriteFiles(DataTable table, String fileName, int batchSize)
    {
        int batchNum = 0;          
        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            done = ExportPartition(fileName, table, batchSize, batchNum++);
        }
    }

    void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt = GetData();
        string fileName = GetFileNameWithSaveDialog(); 
        int batchSize = 25000;
        WriteFiles(dt, fileName, batchSize);
    }
```

Comment: I have implemented this, however it throws an IO Exception on the TextWriter Constructor.  This is the error message: 

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\afannin1\Equipment\HBSSensorDataClient\HBSDataClient\HBSDataClient\bin\Debug\Partitions--0..csv' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Are you seeing two dots in the filename (..csv) ? The extension is probably including the dot, I'll update the format string. The file being in use feels odd, did you have it open in another application (such as a text editor, or previous running instance of the program)?

Comment: I was able to fix that problem and the problem with the extension.  The application is writing the files now, however the while loop used in the implementation is not terminating.

Comment: @Andrew, I updated both the syntax and the use case. First, it passes the filename as a string, rather than the entire dialog (which we can't dispose in the loop anyway, so I also changed to a using{} for the writer). The filename now also uses the directory name from the input file name, if it is a full path. I compiled and ran these methods ok on some dummy data. (Full src http://pastebin.com/Y3tXUJgL)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
        for (int i = 0; i < 103; ++i)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            r[0] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            r[1] = i.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        WriteCsvFile(dt, 25, @"C:\temp\test.txt");
    }

    public static string[] ToStringArray(DataRow row)
    {
        var arr = new string[row.Table.Columns.Count];
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = row[j].ToString();
            if((arr[j]??"").Contains(","))
                throw new Exception("This will end badly...");
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void WriteCsvFile(DataTable table, int maxCount, string fileName)
    {
        if (table.Rows.Count <= maxCount)
            WriteCsvFile(table, maxCount, fileName, 0);
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < (table.Rows.Count / maxCount + 1); ++i)
            {
                var partFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), string.Format("{0}-part{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), i+1, Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
                WriteCsvFile(table, maxCount, partFileName, i * maxCount);
            }
    }

    public static void WriteCsvFile(DataTable table, int maxCount, string fileName, int startIndex)
    {
        using(var fs = File.Create(fileName))
        using(var w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < Math.Min(table.Rows.Count, startIndex + maxCount); i++)
                w.WriteLine(String.Join(",", ToStringArray(table.Rows[i])));
            w.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```